# Regex, get substring between scope and inside double quotes

Tags: regex

I have something like

`bala bla bla bla /*|}"'?-789546 {{tag attribute="attribute_value" second_attribute="another_value"}} bala bla bla bla /*-789546`

and i need to get sting inside double quotes to single quotes between `{{` and `}}` for attributes. I have next expression `{{.*(").*?(").*}}`.
Every help would be very appriciate, thank's.

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: @Thefourthbird it doesn't matter, i use online tool https://regex101.com/

Comment: @The fourth bird sorry, for bad question, i need just search content inside double quotes that between `{{` and `}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{(.*?)\}}` - get text between {{ and }}

then

`"(.*?)"` - get text between double quotes

Since you asked to combine these two,

then

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|{)[^"}]*"([^"]*)"
```

Tested the same using regex101

https://regex101.com/r/Y9bLcM/1/

Comment: ok, how it combine, get text between double quotes that inside `{{` and `}}`

Comment: The last regex is not bound to {{ and }} https://regex101.com/r/mfBcFG/1

Answer (score 0):

Try `(\{\{)?([a-z\_]+\=?\"[a-z\_ 1-9]+\")+(\}\})?`.

This will let you access the content in the two parenthesis

Comment: It give me attribute with value but i need only value of attribute that in `{{` and `}}`

Comment: If you only get value then there lot's of chances that you might end up getting value out of the scope of parenthesis, so one possible solution is that you need to access the parenthesis content first and then in that content you need to get value within quotes

Comment: sorry for the answer there i want to post it as a comment